# Google Maps Streetview: Controls UI like on maps.google.com

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am making a Google Streetview application, using the Google Maps API v3.
However I noticed that the UI of the controls like zoomControl, panControl, and linkControl is different from the controls on maps.google.com.

I am especially interested in using the mouse cursor for navigation instead of the linkControls (arrows). On maps.google.com the mouse cursor shows you which direction you can navigate to, instead of having to click the arrows. This results in a much nicer and smoother navigation.

mouse cursor example: [maps.google.com](https://www.google.nl/maps/@52.0928705,5.1218582,3a,75y,350.32h,74.49t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sh290W7kxXLPXoZztaXq2SQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=nl)

linkControls example: http://www.clearblocks.nl/maps/index.html

I am getting the feeling that the UI of the controls on maps.google.com are just not supported (yet) in the Maps API v3. But I'm not sure about that. Also, I cannot find much information about others who are dealing with this problem. Does anybody have any experience with this, or know how to get the same controls UI as maps.google.com?

I'm guessing that smooth transition between pictures is also not supported in v3. Has anybody found a way to make that work?

Thanks!